# How to return list elements using specific indexes?

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerics

I have a list `BB={3, 5, 10}` and a list `FF = {1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), -((-3 + 7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))}`

Each element of the list `FF` I can return like this `FF[[i]]` where `i = 1, 2, 3` (for instance `FF[[1]] = 1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3])`)

But I would like to return each element of the list `FF` not by index running through the values `i=1,2,3` but by using the list `BB` elements that are related to the list `i` in the following way: `1` associated with `3`, `2` associated with `5` and `3` associated with `10`

So I would like to receive the element `FF[[1]]` like this `FF[3]` (and for the remaining elements `FF[[2]]` like this `FF[5]` and `FF[[3]]` like this `FF[10]`)

Could you show how this can be done?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
BB={3, 5, 10};
FF = {1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), -((-3 + 7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need can be achieved simply by using `AssociationThread`

```
BB = {3, 5, 10};
FF = AssociationThread[BB,
   {1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 
    1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), -((-3 + 7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))}];
(*<|3 -> 1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 5 -> 1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), 
 10 -> -((-3 + 7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))|>*)

FF[3]
(*1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3])*)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Might be worth nothing that the resulting `FF` even supports `FF[[1]]` (which will return the same as `FF[3]`)

Comment: @alex, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @LukasLang it seems that OP understands that your suggested syntax works. They wanted to see if they can have a different notation which is more akin to a functional call.

Comment: Ah sorry, you were referring to the Association! Yes, indeed. You can still use index notation with Associations. Absolutely! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this using straightforward (though somewhat complicated) indexing, rather than using Associations. Define

```
FFF[n_] := FF[[Position[BB, n][[1, 1]]]];
```

Then FFF[3] and FFF[5] are as you expect. Position finds the index in BB that you want, and the [[1,1]] strips away a couple of extra levels of { }.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
BB = {3, 5, 10};
FF = {1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 
   1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), -((-3 + 7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))};

lut = Thread[BB -> FF];

ff[n_Integer] := Lookup[lut, n, "NA"];
```

Test the lookup table:

```
ff /@ Range[10]
```

> {"NA", "NA", 1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), "NA",   1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), "NA",
> "NA", "NA", "NA", -((-3 +     7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))}

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to define FF as a list and then write FF[1]. This evaluates to: {FF-list}[1] what is nonsense.  But what you can do is to use  a new name and use "AssociationThread" as already proposed like e.g.:

```
FF = {1/23 (9 + 2 Sqrt[3]), 
   1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3]), -((-3 + 7 Sqrt[3])/(-7 + Sqrt[3]))};
BB = {3, 5, 10};
ind = AssociationThread[BB -> {1, 2, 3}];
FFF[i_] := FF[[ind[i]]]
```

Now you can e.g. write:

```
FFF[5]

1/23 (9 - 2 Sqrt[3])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Hi @Daniel, I don't think it is nonsense. I'm sure that if OP knew about associations then they would't have used a list! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to extract elements of `FF` using the values of `BB` (rather than their indices):

```
Extract[FF,PositionIndex[BB][3]]
```

$$
\frac{1}{23} \left(9+2 \sqrt{3}\right)
$$